# GridSearchCV takes too long to run

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I have been working on the below script for sentimental analysis and am running into some problems related to the performance of the Grid search - it's taking a very long time to complete & I wonder if there is either something I am doing wrong or something I could do better to make it faster.

Would anybody be able to suggest speed/performance improvements I could make?

Thanks in advance!

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(),parameters,cv=5,return_train_score=True,n_jobs=-1)
grid_search.fit(X,y)
grid_search.best_params_
```

I've imported required libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If this takes a long time, it's because you have a lot of parameters to test (and probably a large data set).

The only way to speed up the process is to remove some parameters from your parameter grid.

You can also try [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)

> Unlike GridSearchCV, not all parameter values are tried out, but a fixed number of parameters are sampled from the specified distributions. The number of parameters tried is given by n_iter. (default: n_iter=10)